# How to fast-forward or rewind an HTML5 video to a certain time point

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to write some JavaScript to do this and I can't figure out why my method isn't working.

```
var vid = document.getElementById('myvid'), 
    ticks = 50, // number of frames during fast-forward
    frms = 10, // number of milleseconds between frames in fast-forward/rewind
    endtime = 24.0; // time to fast-forward/remind to (in seconds)

// fast-forward/rewind video to end time 
var tdelta = (endtime - vid.currentTime)/ticks; 
for ( var i = 0; i < ticks; ++i )
{
   (function(j){
       setTimeout(function() {
             vid.currentTime = vid.currentTime + tdelta * j;
       }, j * frms);
   })(i);
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f90yu2t4/1/

Are HTML videos just not advanced enough to support this kind of rapid movement from place to place in the video?

Answer (score 11):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function vidplay() {
       var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
       var button = document.getElementById("play");
       if (video.paused) {
          video.play();
          button.textContent = "||";
       } else {
          video.pause();
          button.textContent = ">";
       }
    }

    function restart() {
        var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
        video.currentTime = 0;
    }

    function skip(value) {
        var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
        video.currentTime += value;
    }      
</script>


<body>        

<video id="Video1" >
//  Replace these with your own video files. 
     <source src="demo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
     <source src="demo.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
     HTML5 Video is required for this example. 
     <a href="demo.mp4">Download the video</a> file. 
</video>

<div id="buttonbar">
    <button id="restart" onclick="restart();">[]</button> 
    <button id="rew" onclick="skip(-10)">&lt;&lt;</button>
    <button id="play" onclick="vidplay()">&gt;</button>
    <button id="fastFwd" onclick="skip(10)">&gt;&gt;</button>
</div>         
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Two things:

For JSFiddle, the code is already wrapped in window.onload, code inside another window.onload isn't actually executed. You should remove the wrapper (at least when using JSFiddle).

Second, in the setTimeout function, `vid.currentTime = vid.currentTime + tdelta * j;` doesn't work as intended because the second instance of `vid.currentTime` isn't a constant start time. You should assign a startTime before the setTimeout function, and have `vid.currentTime = startTime + tdelta * j;`

With those changes, check it out here:
updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f90yu2t4/8/

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it's at all possible to make it a smooth fast-forward or is it pretty much guaranteed to be choppy?

Comment: It's running fairly smoothly on my computer, but you might have more luck changing video.playbackRate to a high number until you hit your seek time (instead of changing currentTime). That might only work for fastfowarding though-- not sure if it works with negative numbers for rewinding.

Comment: It might also be beneficial to pause the video when seeking through it, then play it.